# php.log come to 15GB

Tags: php, ubuntu, logging, nginx, opcache

I've found on my nginx's logs a file named `php.log` with this content repeatly

```
Usage: php5 [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
   php5 [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
   php5 [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
   php5 [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
   php5 [options] -S <addr>:<port> [-t docroot]
   php5 [options] -- [args...]
   php5 [options] -a

  -a               Run interactively
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -r <code>        Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
  -B <begin_code>  Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines
  -R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
  -F <file>        Parse and execute <file> for every input line
  -E <end_code>    Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines
  -H               Hide any passed arguments from external tools.
  -S <addr>:<port> Run with built-in web server.
  -t <docroot>     Specify document root <docroot> for built-in web server.
  -s               Output HTML syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Output source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.

  args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
                   starts with - or script is read from stdin

  --ini            Show configuration file names

  --rf <name>      Show information about function <name>.
  --rc <name>      Show information about class <name>.
  --re <name>      Show information about extension <name>.
  --rz <name>      Show information about Zend extension <name>.
  --ri <name>      Show configuration for extension <name>.
```

It is arrived up to 15GB. It is always created rather than if I delete it.
With `lsof php.log` it show:

```
COMMAND     PID                USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
php-loop.  1331 opcache_kiteblue_it    1w   REG  202,1 60204481 1179685 php.log
```

And with `ps aux | grep php-loop` it show:

```
1002      1331  0.0  0.0  26092   380 ?        S     2015 108:49 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/php-loop.pl /usr/bin/php5 -b /var/php-nginx/142902709323098.sock/socket
```

The content of php-loop: http://pastebin.com/Evk3Hvxe

I've `Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS`. I've nginx and ngx_pagespeed and only one site with wordpress and some plugins like `W3 total cache` for caching.

I have a presentiment the error come to `opcache - ngx_pagespeed`

Can you give me some help?
Am I under attacking? 
What could I do?